# How to check my internet access on Android?

Tags: android

What I really want is, when the user has no connection, I want to show some dialog that he or she has no connection.

I tried to put this on my MainActivity but still didn't work.

```
public boolean isOnline() {
 ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
 return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();

}
```

I also used this one but it didn't also work:

```
public class ConnectionChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
      @Override
      public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent )
      {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService( Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE );
        NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        NetworkInfo mobNetInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(     ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE );
        if ( activeNetInfo != null )
        {
          Toast.makeText( context, "Active Network Type : " + activeNetInfo.getTypeName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }
        if( mobNetInfo != null )
        {
          Toast.makeText( context, "Mobile Network Type : " + mobNetInfo.getTypeName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }
      }
    }
```

I added this on my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, I would really appreciate it a lot. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this link can help you a bit further: [Broadcastreceiver to obtain ServiceState information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846271/broadcastreceiver-to-obtain-servicestate-information/4846452#4846452)

You could past the mentined CommunicationManager code in your activity, or better, if you need access from more activities, you could also declare the class as static in the Application Singletin instance and call it from there as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846271/broadcastreceiver-to-obtain-servicestate-information/4846452#4846452)

You also need to register the BroadcastReceiver in your application manifest:

```
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:name="com.project.mobile.controller.comm.ConnectivityReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 2):

```
    public static boolean haveInternet(Context ctx) {
         NetworkInfo info = (NetworkInfo) ((ConnectivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();
         if (info == null || !info.isConnected()) {
            return false;
         }
         return true;
    }
```

If the boolean Method returns true then there is Internet connection if false No Connection..

```
if(haveInternet(ActivityName.this)==true){
   //Some code
}else{
   Toast.makeText(ActivityName.this,"No Internet Connection",      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
 }
```

Also see this for further help.. [Internet Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238921/android-detect-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available)...

Comment: Should I just put this on my Main Activity?

Comment: yes u can put this in your activity. but convectional way is that use one of the global class like internetUtil and paste there after use anywhere in your code

Comment: Yes you can put this in your Activity..You got it?

Answer (score 1):

Just use this method

```
private boolean isNetworkConnected(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo network = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (network != null) {
            return network.isAvailable();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

u can check your inter connection with the help of ConnectivityManager class.
i have given one function that u can use in code.

```
 public static boolean
 CheckInternet(Context context)      {
         ConnectivityManager connec =(ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = > connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

        android.net.NetworkInfo mobile =connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
```

Here if condition check for wifi and mobile network is available
or not.  If anyone of them isavailable or connected then it will
return true, otherwise false;

```
 if (wifi.isConnected()) {          
return true;        
} else if
 (!mobile.isConnected()) 
{           
return false;       
} else if
 (mobile.isConnected())
 {          
return true;        
} return false;
}
```

after using of this function u need 2 just check the condition like

```
 if (CheckInternet(getBaseContext())) 
 {   
 //connection successfull 

 }  else 

{ Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Please Check InternetConnectionToast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
}
```

enjoy

Comment: Should I just past this on my Activities?

Comment: yes you can paste in your activity... but if you need it in all the activity then you have to make one class for that and paste this function in it .. or make one class and make the above function as static in it... so you can call it using class name, you just need to pass the current activity's context ....

Comment: @chirag : seems @milind copy/paste your response :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373930/how-to-check-network-connection-enable-or-disable-in-wifi-and-3gdata-plan-in-mo/5374040#5374040

Answer (score 0):

The above methods work when you are connected to a Wi-Fi source or via cell phone data packs. But in case of Wi-Fi connection there are cases when you are further asked to Sign-In like in Cafe. So in that case your application will fail as you are connected to Wi-Fi source but not with the Internet.

This method works fine.

```
public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/");
            HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "test");
            urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
            urlc.setConnectTimeout(1000); // mTimeout is in seconds
            urlc.connect();
            if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("warning", "Error checking internet connection", e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    return false;

}
```

Please use this in a separate thread from the main thread as it makes a network call and will throw NetwrokOnMainThreadException if not followed.