# Test Internet connection changes-android

Tags: android, android-intent, connection, android-networking

I've searched this and I can't resolve the problem, look at this code checked on other examples:

```
public class EntryActivity extends Activity {

public Boolean isNetAvailable(Context con)  {

    try{
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)       
                                                                  con.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo wifiInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        NetworkInfo mobileInfo =connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        if (wifiInfo.isConnected() || mobileInfo.isConnected()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
```

this method works well when I call it in **onCreate** method, like this:

```
if (isNetAvailable(getApplicationContext())) {
        Toast.makeText(EntryActivity.this,
            "You have Internet Connection, wait a moment to sincronize" +
            "Metar's stations", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
               .show();
         Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
         startActivity(myIntent);

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(EntryActivity.this,
            "You Do not have Internet Connection",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        EntryActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(
                Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
            }
```

This only works for the first Internet connection Check! the problem is, if Wifi is off the user should leaves the app or turns Wi-Fi on.But, if He turns it on, I don't have access to that change and I can't advance to my other activity. 
So, If in the beggining the internet connection status is down, i want keep checking if the User turns it On to advanve to other activity. 
What can I do?

Comment: check internet connection availability in onResume() method

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846271/broadcastreceiver-to-obtain-servicestate-information/4846452#4846452

Comment: Sankar V, in onResume it doesn't check just one time , like onCreate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you android manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="com.softteco.clivero.receivers.ConnectionReceiver" >
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

And create class:

```
public class ConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        boolean newConnectionState = isConnected(context);
    }
    private boolean isConnected(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivityManager.getAllNetworkInfo();
        boolean ifConnected = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
            NetworkInfo connection = info[i];
            if (connection.getState().equals(NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)) {
                ifConnected = true;
            }
        }
        return ifConnected;
    }

}
```

It's one of the possible variants. Hope it will help you.

Comment: let's try, I will answer soon ;)

Comment: tell me just one thing,how can I apply this example in my code?

Comment: Hm, in you activity you should register some custom broadcast receiver, which will get intents from ConnectionReceiver#onReceive method. And depends on broadcast, that ConnectionReceiver sent show appropriate activity. Have you got the basic idea?

Comment: hmm I'm understanding. But the step of move to the another activity if online like you can see in my code:  EntryActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(
                Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));  
Should be done in the onReceive?

Comment: I mean, this part of the code:
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
         startActivity(myIntent);

Comment: It's better to do in EntryActivity.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to keep checking for Internet connection changes via executing your code at intervals. Instead you need to define a broadcast recievers in your app to listen network changes.

See this answer
[How can I monitor the network connection status in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307237/how-can-i-monitor-the-network-connection-status-in-android)

Comment: humm.. but there's no way to perform a task to keep updating the Internet connection?

Comment: yes. you don't need to do any operation to check internet connection status. Let your reciever listen for statis change. and in its onRecieve store the state to any of your variable in your app that your code can refer to inside the if check before doing any operation. simple

Comment: I'm new at android programming and I'm getting  confused to implement a broadcast receiver in my code.. can you tell me how can I call a broadcastReceiver in OnCreate??;)

Answer (score 0):

this may helps you Monitor network connections Wi-Fi, GPRS, UMTS, etc

```
public boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context)
    {
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return info!=null;
    }
```

also make sure you added require permission in `Manifest` File like

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" >
    </uses-permission>
```

Comment: I already know this, my function isNetAvailable already does it ;)

Comment: before reply try it and check it first

Comment: but this only gives me "true if it's connected or false if it's disconnected" right?